# Finding the difference between 2 different sized dataframes with Pandas and update filds acordingly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 CSV files that were created at different dates that I want to compare and I want to update some fields of second one based on diffs from first.

Every item in table consists of 3 rows(you can see that Name_* is not changed)
Also regarding Status column we will always have LISTED, STARTED and PASSED/FAILED values

So second one is base CSV it have all items, first CSV(new one) can be different size(missing one or few items) for example we are missing fourth item 'Name_4'

Rules for updating Cost field we need to have Iteration_First_CSV>Iteration_Second_CSV & Name_First_CSV==Name_Second_CSV & Status_First_CSV==['PASSED','FAILED'](we don't want to update LISTED and STARTED cost)

Rules for updating Status field we need to have Iteration_First_CSV>Iteration_Second_CSV & Name_First_CSV==Name_Second_CSV

This is second CSV
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ48Z.png)

First CSV
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLIRk.png)

Result should be like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Yld.png)

I started to work on 'Cost' fields update:

```
df_second.loc[((df_first['Name'].eq(df_second['Name']))&(df_first['Cost'].ge(df_second['Cost']))&(df_first['Status'].isin(['PASSED','FAILED']))), 'Cost'] = df_first['Cost']
```

but this is resulting in `"Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable"` error

Comment: Do not post images: post dataframes as dictionaries, so they can easily be copied and included in code

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest approach would be filtering the rows you want to check, merging, making changes and "rebuilding" the dataframe. If you have a lot of data this might not be optimal.

```
df1_filtered = df1[~df1.Status.isin(["LISTED", "STARTED"])
df2_filtered = df2[~df2.Status.isin(["LISTED", "STARTED"])

columns = df2.columns.tolist()

df2_filtered = df2_filtered.merge(df1_filtered, how="left", on=["Name"], suffixes=("", "_1")

df2_filtered.loc[df2.iteration_1 > df2.iteration, "Cost"] = df2_filtered.Cost_1

df2 = pd.concat([df2[df2.Status.isin(["LISTED", "STARTED"])], df2_filtered[columns]]).sort_values(["A", "B", "Name"])
```

This is done just from out of my head, so there might be small issues.

Note:
Maybe it is not possible. But looking at the files, the first thing I would do is changing the format. It seems to have duplicated information (which is bad for multiple reasons). I don't know the exact details of the dataset but from what I see I would just keep:

- a, b, name, cost, status_passed, status_started, status_listed, date, iteration.

The status_* columns could be boolean. I think it would be a better structure (unless I'm missing something) and it would be way easier to operate in Pandas and